# Modify a php limit text function adding some kind of offset to it

Tags: php

Maybe you guys can help:

I have a variable called $bio with bio data.

```
$bio = "Hello, I am John, I'm 25, I like fast cars and boats. I work as a blogger and I'm way cooler then the author of the question";
```

I search the $bio using a set of functions to search for a certain word, lets say **"author"** which **adds a span class around that word**, and I get:

```
$bio = "Hello, I am John, I'm 25, I like fast cars and boats. I work as a blogger and I'm way cooler then the <span class=\"highlight\">author</span> of the question";
```

I use a function to limit the text to 85 chars:

```
$bio = limit_text($bio,85);
```

**The problem** is when there are more then 80 chars before the word **"author"** in **$bio**.
When the `limit_text()` is applied, I won't see the highlighted word author.

**What I need is for the limit_text() function to work as normal, adding all the words that contain the span class highlight at the end.
Something like this:**

```
*"This is the limited text to 85 chars, but there are no words with the span class highlight so I am putting to be continued ... **author**, **author2** (and all the other words that have a span class highlight around them separate by comma "*
```

Hope you understood what I mean, if not, please comment and I'll try to explain better.

Here is my `limit_text()` function:

```
function limit_text($text, $length){ // Limit Text
        if(strlen($text) > $length) {
        $stringCut = substr($text, 0, $length);
        $text = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' '));
        }
        return $text;
    }
```

**UPDATE**:

```
$xturnons = str_replace(",", ", ", $xturnons);
$xbio = str_replace(",", ", ", $xbio);

$xbio = customHighlights($xbio,$toHighlight); 
$xturnons = customHighlights($xturnons,$toHighlight);

$xbio = limit_text($xbio,85);
$xturnons = limit_text($xturnons,85);
```

The `customHighlights` function which adds the span class highlighted:

```
function addRegEx($word){ // Highlight Words
        return "/" . $word . '[^ ,\,,.,?,\.]*/i';
    }
    function highlight($word){
        return "<span class='highlighted'>".$word[0]."</span>";
    }
    function customHighlights($searchString,$toHighlight){
        $searchFor = array_map('addRegEx',$toHighlight);
        $result = preg_replace_callback($searchFor,'highlight',$searchString);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: You need to get your requirements straightened out: What do you expect it to do if 'author' is say the 86th word out of 86? 100th out of 150? 100th out of 200? etc. Once you decide what the behaviour should be, implementing it should be easy!

Comment: If "author" is the word 150 (lets assume all 150 words have 800 chars), author having 5 chars, the limit text should start from char 715 and end at char 800, containing the author word.

Comment: @John3136, I think the OP wants something like, let's say the keyword is FOO, the limit is 12, and the sentence is *bar baz FOO bim boom*, the result should *baz FOO bim *

Comment: yes, exactly, any ideas?

Comment: As per my first comment: what are the rules? why does "bar baz FOO bim boom" go to "baz FOO bim"? Why isn't it "FOO bim boom"? Is FOO "centered" in the results? Can there be more than 1 highlighted word? - what if the two highlighted words are 90 chars apart? - until you can clearly state what it is you are trying to do, you have got very little chance of being able to do it!

Comment: @webmasters: should the sentence *end* with `author` or *start* with it? or centered - and if so, how many words should there be before it and after it? 40, 40? Also, if you are basing on words, what if there is a really long word in the sentence? Maybe you want to impose a limit on number of characters before and after author?

Comment: Hmm, you submitted some very good points... 1. About the author, from a grammar point it would make sense to echo the sentence and limit it to 85 chars, followed by author and "..." (the author being all the words that have the span class highlight around them

Comment: Kind reminder to award your bounty to any of the three answers given. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make sure you don't break words apart by shortening the string. Then you need to append all of the `<span class="highlight">` tokens to the end of the shortened string. Here is what I came up with (in about **8** lines!):

```
function limit_text($text, $length){
    if( strlen( $text) < $length) {
        return $text;
    }

    // Truncate the string without breaking words
    list( $wrapped) = explode("\n", wordwrap( $text, $length));

    // Get the span of text occurring after the wrapped string
    $remainder = substr( $text, strlen( $wrapped));

    // Add the "to be continued" to $wrapped
    $wrapped .= ' to be continued ... ';

    // Now, grab all of the <span class="highlight"></span> tags in the $remainder
    preg_match_all( '#<span class="highlight">[^<]+</span>#i', $remainder, $matches);

    // Add the <span> tags to the end of the string, separated by a comma, if present
    $wrapped .= implode( ', ', $matches[0]);

    return $wrapped;
}
```

Now, with your original test:

```
$bio = "Hello, I am John, I'm 25, I like fast cars and boats. I work as a blogger and I'm way cooler then the <span class=\"highlight\">author</span> of the question";
$bio = limit_text( $bio,85);
var_dump( htmlentities( $bio));
```

This [outputs](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vxBE7X):

```
string(165) "Hello, I am John, I'm 25, I like fast cars and boats. I work as a blogger and I'm way to be continued ... <span class="highlight">author</span>"
```

Now, another test with multiple `<span>` tags:

This [outputs](http://codepad.viper-7.com/c7R54g):

```
$bio = 'Hello, what about a <span class="highlight">span tag</span> before the limit? Or what if I have many <span class="highlight">span tags</span> <span class="highlight">after</span> <span class="highlight">the</span> limit?';
$bio = limit_text( $bio,85);
var_dump( htmlentities( $bio));

string(308) "Hello, what about a <span class="highlight">span tag</span> before the limit? Or what to be continued ... <span class="highlight">span tags</span>, <span class="highlight">after</span>, <span class="highlight">the</span>"
```

If you have more test cases, or have a modification to the function above, let me know and I can fix it!

Comment: @webmasters - Sure! If you find a test case that breaks it, please post it along with an explanation of what is wrong so I can modify the function. Note that I just updated the function to be compatible with PHP versions < 5.4.

Comment: Testing it works excet: Add the <span> tags to the end of the string, separated by a comma, if present

Comment: @webmasters - It should work with that test case, see my second example - It has multiple `<span>` tags, and they are all added to the end of the string and are separated by a comma. Can you post the exact string you used, along with the desired output?

Comment: I use "highlighted" class instead of "highlight" , modifyed it byt still not working.... Let me post the exact code. One second.

Comment: I have updated the question with all the code I have used, please take a look. The code works with spans in the 85 chars limit, but does not add the tags at the end.

Comment: @webmasters - I need the values of `$xbio` and `$xturnons` before you call `limit_text()` in order to understand what is going wrong. Can you do `var_dump( $xbio, $xturnons);` before `limit_text()` and post that output?

Comment: Can I give you a link to the actual site, with var dump? It has adult content

Comment: @webmasters - Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13133/discussion-between-nickb-and-webmasters)

Comment: @nickb: kinda hard for me to see what's special in your answer from mine, that it wasn't just enough to drop a comment on mine so I could work with the OP on?

I kinda put my time into this, to have you just coming 15 minutes later and swiping it away.

Comment: @DvirAzulay - I have no clue what you're expecting, our approaches are entirely different and actually do two completely different things. I'm not swiping away anything - Anybody is free to answer any question they want.

Comment: Ty for the help, my internet connection went down

Answer (score 4):

This change to your `limit_text` function will take the text, and cut it if it's longer than the given `$length`. If you pass a `$needle` to it, it will search for the first occurrence of it, and end your sentence with it.

Also, if the text is cut before it's actual length, it will add `$addition` to it, while still preserving the limit of `$length` characters.

I've included a usage and a sample output based on your given below:

```
<?php
/**
*   $text - The text to cut from
*   $length - The amount of characters that should be returned
*   $needle - If needle is given and found in the text, and it is 
*             at least $length far from the start of the string - it will end the sentence with it.
*   $addition - If the sentence was cut in the middle, will add it to the end of it.
**/
function limit_text($text, $length, $needle="", $addition="...") { 
    if(strlen($text) > $length) {
        $length -= strlen($addition);

        $start = 0;
        $trimLast = true;
        if (!empty($needle)) {
            $needleStart = strpos($text, $needle);

            if ($needleStart > $length) {
                $length -= strlen($needle);
                $start = $needleStart + strlen($needle) - $length;
                $trimLast = false;
            }
        }

        $stringCut = substr($text, max(0, $start), $length);
        if ($start > 0) {
            $stringCut = substr($stringCut, strpos($stringCut, ' ')+1);
        }
        if ($trimLast) {
            $lastWhitespace = strrpos($stringCut, ' ');
            $stringCut = substr($stringCut, 0, $lastWhitespace);
        }

        // split into words (so we won't replace words that contain it in the middle)
        // and wrap $needle with <span class="highlighted"></span>
        if (!empty($needle)) {
            $words = explode(" ", $stringCut);
            $needles = array_keys($words, $needle);
            foreach ($needles as $needleKey) {
                $words[$needleKey] = "<span class=\"highlighted\">$needle</span>";
            }

            $stringCut = implode(" ", $words);
        }
        $text = $stringCut.$addition;
    }
    return $text;
}

$bio = "Hello, I am John, I'm 25, I like fast cars and boats. I work as a blogger and I'm way cooler then the author of the question";
$text = limit_text($bio, 85, "author");
var_dump($text);
```

**Output**:

```
string (111) "fast cars and boats. I work as a blogger and I'm way cooler then the <span class="highlighted">author</span>..."
```

Comment: He's like that problogger dude;) Read a couple of years back about a post where he sat at the beach making money from blogging

Comment: Ty for the answer btw... I have a few questions: 1. can I have more values like author1, author2, author3?

Comment: If needle is given and found in the text, it will end the sentence with it. --- It should keep the lengts of 85 chars though... for example if author is the 2nd word I don't want the sentence to end before it reachers 85 chars

Comment: @webmasters: I would love to edit further, what is the expected behavior when given multiple values?

Comment: Ty very much, I am just a webmaster not a programmer and I could not see myself doing this things :) ... highlight them when they are inside the first 85 chars and add the ones which are not after, separated by comma

Comment: @webmasters: I've just updated my answer with a better function, supporting a few edge cases I found.

What do you mean by highlighting? Surround in `<span>`'s? I thought you had another function doing that; if not, let me know and I'll add that in.

Comment: @webmasters: Added replacing of "author" with `<span class="highlighted">author</span>`. Let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: @webmasters: Should the text be cut at 85 characters *with* the HTML replacements or *without* it? I mean, should I count 85 characters *after* adding the `<span>`'s, or before (like it does now?)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your requirements, this should do what you want:

```
function get_highlighted_string($s)
{
    return '<span class="highlight">' . htmlspecialchars($s) . '</span>';
}

function limit_text($text, $max_length, array $keywords = array(), $continued = '...')
{
    // highlights to put after the cut string
    $extra = array();

    // highlight keywords
    if ($keywords) {
        $re = '~\b(' . join('|', array_map('preg_quote', $keywords, array('~'))) . ')\b~i';
        // get all matches and capture their positions as well
        if (preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
            // we reverse the matches by position to make replacement easier
            foreach (array_reverse($matches[1]) as $match) {
                // $match[0] = match
                // $match[1] = start position
                $match_len = strlen($match[0]);
                if ($match[1] + $match_len <= $max_length) {
                    // still fits in cut string
                    $match_replacement = get_highlighted_string($match[0]);
                    $text = substr_replace($text, $match_replacement, $match[1], $match_len);
                    // update max length
                    $max_length = $max_length - $match_len + strlen($match_replacement);
                } else {
                    // will not fit in the cut string, so we place it outside
                    array_unshift($extra, get_highlighted_string($match[0]));
                }
            }
        }
        // use wordwrap and strcspn to cut the string by word boundaries
        if (strlen($text) > $max_length) {
            $text = substr($text, 0, strcspn(wordwrap($text, $max_length, "\0"), "\0")) . " $continued";
        }
    }

    if ($extra) {
        // append what we couldn't fit in the cut string
        $text .= ' ' . join(', ', $extra);
    }

    return $text;
}
```

Example:

```
echo limit_text("Hello, I like fast cars and boats. I work as a blogger I'm way cooler then the author of the question", 85, array('author', 'question'));

Hello, I like fast cars and boats. I work as a blogger I'm way cooler then the <span class="highlight">author</span> ... <span class="highlight">question</span>
```

In the example, the cut-off is exactly at `author` so that highlight comes before the `...` while the `question` keywords gets put behind.

Another example:

```
echo limit_text("Hello, I am John, I'm 25, I like fast cars and boats. I work as a blogger and I'm way cooler then the author of the question", 85, array('author', 'question'));

Hello, I am John, I'm 25, I like fast cars and boats. I work as a blogger and I'm way ... <span class="highlight">author</span>, <span class="highlight">question</span>
```

Both keywords are beyond the 85 character marker, so they are appended at the back, comma separated.

Let me know if this works for you :)